Given a level surface M, show that two given vectors are a basis for the tangent space of M at a point
I've been doing some light revision on differential geometry and I'm not yet comfortable with level surfaces. Any help is appreciated.
Question:
Given a surface S defined by $z=x^2+3xy-5y^2$ Show that the unit vectors (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) form a basis for the tangent space of the surface at p=(0,0,0)
What I have so far:
So I'm used to tackling this kinds of questions by taking a local parameterization of the surface X(u,v) then taking the partial derivatives of that, which would yield the tangent vectors of curves on the surface and passing through p.
In this case : $X(u,v)=(u,v,u^2+3uv-5v^2)$ could work as a local parameterization around p of S since $X(0,0)=(0,0,0)$ =p
and the partial derivatives with respect to u and v respectively and evaluated at (0,0,0) would give us $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ which are vectors tangent to curves that pass through p and so belong to the tangent plane at of S at p and form a basis because they are linearly independent.
Is my approach correct here? I can't think of anything else but at the same time it seems a little hand wavey. Also, if my approach is correct, is there any other approach that would involve working with the surface in level form instead of parameterizing it?
Thank you all.

You don't need to pick a parametrization. A vector $\mathbf{v}$ is tangent to an implicit surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ at a regular point $p$ iff the directional derivative of $f$ along $\mathbf{v}$ (at $p$) is zero, i.e. $\mathbf{v}$ is perpendicular to the gradient of $f$.

@arkeet Aaaah I see, I guess I'm a little bit confused still thinking about the grad of f when it comes to implicit surfaces.

@arkeet Is my approach, especially in regards of picking parameterization, also correct?

Your reasoning is correct. Also, notice that $g(x,y,z) = z - x^2 - 3xy - 5y^2 = 0$, so $\nabla g$ is orthogonal to the level surface and hence the basis of the orthogonal compliment of $\nabla g$ at a given point is a basis of the tangent space
